# Creating default object from empty value - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, variable-assignment

I dont know how fix this error, my code:

```
$subscriptions = Auth::user()->subscriptions;

foreach($subscriptions as $subscription)
{
    $subs = Subscription::find($subscription->id);

    $subs->subscriptionstatus_id = 0;

    $subs->save();

}
```

and laravel response with `Creating default object from empty value` in line when I assign `0`, what can I do?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the variable `$subs` is null, and needs to check if has something:

```
$subscriptions = Auth::user()->subscriptions;

foreach($subscriptions as $subscription)
{
    $subs = Subscription::find($subscription->id);

    // Check if exist the subs record
    if (count($subs) > 0)
    {
        $subs->subscriptionstatus_id = 0;

        $subs->save();
    }
}
```

I was added that validation and work's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when you try to set properties on a `null` value. For example,

```
$obj = null;
$obj->prop = 0; // Creating default object from empty value
```

Therefore, it seems as if your `find()` statement returned `null`, meaning you don't have a `Subscription` with the id you're trying to find.

Comment: I will review the subscription variable, to determine if that, thanks